# Fetching the animations added to a SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit

Am trying to get the animation added to a SCNNode for a give key. Looks like the function is deprecated (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable/1524020-animation) and no alternate is provided in documentation.

Am trying to create an animation editor and all modifications to the node are added as CAKeyframeAnimation which needs to be then fetched to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement is [`-animationPlayerForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable/2866026-animationplayerforkey?language=objc).